# How to overide UIToolbar method with later version of iOS 4.2

Tags: iphone, custom-controls, uitoolbar, iphone-sdk-3.2, iphone-sdk-4.1

This code works fine with iPad Simulator 4.2, but not with later version of iOS4.3 or after that.I am not able to Override the UIToolbar class methods.

```
@implementation UIToolbar (CustomImage)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ToolBar.png"] retain];
    [image drawInRect:rect];
    [image release];    
}
 //return 'best' size to fit given size. does not actually resize view. Default is return existing view size
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
    CGSize result = [super sizeThatFits:size];
    result.height = 80;
    return result;
};
```

What would be the alternate solution for this ?Please guide me.
In later version ..- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect is never called .

**Running with iPad Simulator 4.2 code works fine but with iPad Simulator 4.3 drawRect in never called.**

Below is the Screenshot of Toolbar:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

```
@implementation UIToolbar (UIToolbarCategory)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
    if([self isMemberOfClass: [UIToolbar class]]){
        [super drawRect:rect];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bar_gradient.png"];
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: Working in the same way ...as my one.There is no differnce. :(

Comment: I've actually used that method with success in ios 4.3. Are you sure you don't mean that it's not working in ios 5?

Answer (score 1):

you are implementing it as a category, you need to subclass UIToolBar based on the iOS5 change log

> In the iOS 5 beta, the UINavigationBar,
>   UIToolbar, and UITabBar implementations have changed so that the
>   drawRect: method is not called on instances of these classes unless it
>   is implemented in a subclass.
>
> Apps that have re-implemented drawRect: in a category on any of these
>   classes will find that the drawRect: method isn’t called.
>
> UIKit does link-checking to keep the method from being called in apps
>   linked before iOS 5 but does not support this design on iOS 5 or
>   later. Apps can either:
>
> - Use the customization API for bars that in iOS 5 and later, which is    the preferred way.
> - Subclass UINavigationBar (or the other bar classes) and override drawRect: in the subclass.